# Applying css to Dynamic button

Tags: css

Hi  i have a requirement to add style sheet to dynamic buttons in Master page. This is master.cs (codebehind) i had used cssClass for button like below.

```
   private void LoadButtons(string TabCode)

      {

        DataSet dsItems = brItems.GetItems(TabCode);
        for (int i = 0; i < dsItems.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
         {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Text = dsItems.Tables[0].Rows[i]["MenuName"].ToString();
            btn.PostBackUrl = dsItems.Tables[0].Rows[i]["URL"].ToString();
            pnlLeft.Controls.Add(btn);
            btn.CssClass = "Button1";
            pnlLeft.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));

        }

    }
```

And my StyleSheet is:

```
  .Button1
      {
        background: url(images/btnbackground.gif) no-repeat 25% 50% #FF8800;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: Georgia, serif;
        vertical-align: middle;
        color:Gray;
        border-spacing: 25px;
```

}
This style sheet is applying to other controls which i have added (not dynamically) in master page.But it is not applying to dynamic buttons

Comment: After the button is added, what is the resulting html?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the style what you have applied is being overridden. Try adding `!important` for each style value.